Distinguish explicit None passed value in Marshmallow schema from default None value
I'm working with marshmallow-dataclass in my APIFlask application to get schemas for my API requests. Now I would like to have a field that can be left empty, be filled with a value, or be set explicitly to None with different behaviour for each.
I currently have something like this:
from marshmallow_dataclass import dataclass

@dataclass
class FooIn:
    bar: str | None = field(default=None)

But now I cannot make a distinction between whether the original JSON contained {"bar": null} or {}. I would like to make this distinction while keeping both JSONs valid, so simply removing the default value is insufficient as {} would no longer be valid input.
I have found one workaround and that is to use some other sort of singleton or sentinel as a default value:
from marshmallow_dataclass import dataclass

class _Undefined: pass
Undefined = _Undefined()

@dataclass
class FooIn:
    bar: str | None = field(default=Undefined)

However, this has two drawbacks for me:

The generated OpenAPI specifications will show this Undefined object as the default value (which is rendered as {}) when I'd rather have it not show this value at all.
The type annotation for FooIn.bar is no longer accurate, as it can also be the instance of _Undefined. If I update the annotation to include this, it will have the undesired side effect of the OpenAPI specs reflecting it as "any" rather than "string or null".

I attempted to remedy issue 1 is to keep the default on None and detect via a @post_load hook whether the original data contained the key or not to set it to my custom sentinel value, but at that point it feels like I'm going down too far a rabbit hole to achieve what I want. Adding metadata={"required": False} to the field call also seemed to have no effect.
Is there any way for me to reliably test whether an input value was in the original data or whether the default value was used?
